# how to use function & ifelse() to sum up the total of negative values?

Tags: r, function

I wrote a simple function to hopefully calculate the total of negative values but failed. Ideally, when I passed a vector into the function, it should give the total count of negative values. Can anyone help, please?

My code:

```
    arg <- c(rnorm(50, 0))
    neg <- 0
    count.negative.fun <- function(x) {
            ifelse(x <= 0, neg = neg +1,)
            return(neg)
     }
```

When I called:

```
  count.negative.fun(arg)
```

It gives me this error message: `"Error in ifelse(x <= 0, neg = neg + 1, ) : 
  unused argument (neg = neg + 1)"`

Comment: Does `sum(arg[arg < 0])` work?

Comment: this seems to sum up the total of negative values, what about sum up the frequency of those negative values(incidents), sorry if I was not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `ifelse` and defining a function, one might do

```
count.negative.fun <- function(x) sum(ifelse(x <= 0, 1, 0))
count.negative.fun(arg)
# [1] 26
```

See `?ifelse`. It returns 1 for those cases when an element of `x` is nonpositive and 0 otherwise. Then we may sum the result.

However, you may also simply write

```
sum(arg < 0)
# [1] 26
```

Comment: thanks so much for your elegant answer. At the risk of digressing, I am curious if in R, the rule of thumb is to avoid write our own function as much as we can? I came to realize R has many useful function that works well with vectorized data.

Comment: @EdwardLin, I'd say that's more about a personal taste and what you are doing rather than rule of thumbs or R. For instance, my second (shorter) approach is shorter than your function name alone. In this case I'd surely always use just `sum(arg < 0)`. Then you may say that the function name could be just `cnf` and `cnf(arg)` is shorter. However, if you keep taking this approach, after several such functions you will lose track of their names. On the other hand, consider a case where you do something complicated (many lines of code). Then, if you are going to do that multiple times...

Comment: ...clearly defining a function is the way to go. But even if you are going to use it just once, you may want to define a function for the sake of readability, especially if the whole project is long. I'd say it becomes about personal preferences when a function takes a couple of lines and it is being used a couple of times as well.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible way is by using `length` function itself. As:

```
length(arg[arg<0])
#[1] 26
```